# Error in extracting several sequences from a .fasta file using a genomic range object as reference

Tags: r, fasta, vcf-variant-call-format, genomicranges

I have a fasta file that corresponds to my reference genome and a vcf file that corresponds to the SNP call of my data. I would like to get the sequence of each one of the SNPs from my fasta.
For that, using R I loaded the vcf file and extract a genomic range object from it using the commands:

```
vcf.fn<-"SNPsAcrossAlltheIndividuals.vcf"
vcf <- readVcf(vcf.fn, verbose=FALSE)
SNPrange <- vcf@rowRanges
```

I extended the position of the SNP to one base each side, but I will not consider it here, since It will add more bias to my question.
After that also using R, I used Rsamtools package to read the fasta using the follow commands:

```
library(Rsamtools)
file_path <- "F1.fasta"
indexFa(file_path)
fa = FaFile("F1.fasta")
```

I checked if all the SNPs (or extended windows) were not out of boundaries of my fasta using this command:

```
   gr = as(seqinfo(fa), "GRanges")
        findOverlaps(gr, SNPrange)
```

And finally, I run the command do get the sequence from the SNPrange using my fasta file. However I got the follow error:

```
  seq_ <-getSeq(fa, SNPrange)
    Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
       record 12177 (chr7:88167221-88167221) failed
      file: F1.fasta
```

I noticed that other people had the same problem, but none got a solution, so I tried to solve it my way. I tried to getSeq for each chromosomes separately:

```
chr1<- gr[seqnames(gr) == "chr1" ]
chr2<- gr[seqnames(gr) == "chr2" ]
chr3<- gr[seqnames(gr) == "chr3" ]
...

seq1 <-getSeq(fa, chr1)
seq2 <-getSeq(fa, chr2)
seq3 <-getSeq(fa, chr3)
...
```

And worked, but there were some chromosomes presenting exactly the same problem:

```
seq7 <-getSeq(fa, chr7)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) :  record 993 (chr7:88167220-88167222) failed
  file: F1.fasta
```

I suspect the problem could be that the positions from which I want to extract the string were "N" in my fasta file. So I tried to locate one of these positions in my fasta file where R showed me an error. And to my surprise, they were not "Ns", but heterozygous bases. However, when I subsetted my data by chromosome, the algorithm was able to identify a Y (C / T) and other heterozygous bases, that is, it has no problem with degenerate bases. So I think that the problem is with the algorithm and not with my data. I used the follow command in bash to extract the seq from the desired position of the fasta file:

```
samtools faidx F1.fasta chr7:88167220-88167222" 
>chr7:88167220-88167222 
> CRA
```

And here is my sessinInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] readr_1.3.1                               limma_3.44.3                             
 [3] ggplot2_3.3.2                             stringr_1.4.0                            
 [5] vcfR_1.12.0                               adegenet_2.1.3                           
 [7] ape_5.4-1                                 ade4_1.7-15                              
 [9] TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene_3.10.0 GenomicFeatures_1.40.1                   
[11] AnnotationDbi_1.50.3                      VariantAnnotation_1.34.0                 
[13] Rsamtools_2.4.0                           Biostrings_2.56.0                        
[15] XVector_0.28.0                            SummarizedExperiment_1.18.2              
[17] DelayedArray_0.14.1                       matrixStats_0.56.0                       
[19] Biobase_2.48.0                            GenomicRanges_1.40.0                     
[21] GenomeInfoDb_1.24.2                       IRanges_2.22.2                           
[23] S4Vectors_0.26.0                          BiocGenerics_0.34.0                      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_1.4-1         seqinr_3.6-1             deldir_0.1-29            ellipsis_0.3.1          
  [5] class_7.3-17             rstudioapi_0.11          farver_2.0.3             bit64_4.0.5             
  [9] fansi_0.4.1              xml2_1.3.2               codetools_0.2-16         splines_4.0.2           
 [13] memuse_4.1-0             cluster_2.1.0            dbplyr_2.0.0             shiny_1.5.0             
 [17] compiler_4.0.2           httr_1.4.2               assertthat_0.2.1         Matrix_1.2-18           
 [21] fastmap_1.0.1            cli_2.1.0                later_1.1.0.1            htmltools_0.5.0         
 [25] prettyunits_1.1.1        tools_4.0.2              igraph_1.2.5             coda_0.19-4             
 [29] gtable_0.3.0             glue_1.4.2               GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.3   reshape2_1.4.4          
 [33] dplyr_1.0.2              rappdirs_0.3.1           gmodels_2.18.1           Rcpp_1.0.5              
 [37] raster_3.3-13            vctrs_0.3.4              spdep_1.1-5              gdata_2.18.0            
 [41] nlme_3.1-148             rtracklayer_1.48.0       pinfsc50_1.2.0           mime_0.9                
 [45] lifecycle_0.2.0          gtools_3.8.2             XML_3.99-0.3             LearnBayes_2.15.1       
 [49] zlibbioc_1.34.0          MASS_7.3-51.6            scales_1.1.1             BSgenome_1.56.0         
 [53] hms_0.5.3                promises_1.1.1           expm_0.999-5             curl_4.3                
 [57] memoise_1.1.0            biomaRt_2.44.4           stringi_1.5.3            RSQLite_2.2.1           
 [61] e1071_1.7-3              permute_0.9-5            boot_1.3-25              BiocParallel_1.22.0     
 [65] spData_0.3.8             rlang_0.4.7              pkgconfig_2.0.3          bitops_1.0-6            
 [69] lattice_0.20-41          purrr_0.3.4              sf_0.9-6                 labeling_0.4.2          
 [73] GenomicAlignments_1.24.0 bit_4.0.4                tidyselect_1.1.0         plyr_1.8.6              
 [77] magrittr_1.5             R6_2.5.0                 generics_0.1.0           DBI_1.1.0               
 [81] withr_2.3.0              mgcv_1.8-31              pillar_1.4.6             units_0.6-7             
 [85] RCurl_1.98-1.2           sp_1.4-2                 tibble_3.0.3             crayon_1.3.4            
 [89] KernSmooth_2.23-17       BiocFileCache_1.12.1     progress_1.2.2           grid_4.0.2              
 [93] blob_1.2.1               vegan_2.5-6              digest_0.6.25            classInt_0.4-3          
 [97] xtable_1.8-4             httpuv_1.5.4             openssl_1.4.3            munsell_0.5.0           
[101] viridisLite_0.3.0        askpass_1.1
```

Comment: findOverlaps doesn't tell you that the snps are out of range. you need to check whether the chromosome length is smaller than your corresponding snp position. you can try findoverlaps with type = "within" .. but just write something to check with chromosome length

Comment: @StupidWolf, I don't know if I understood how your statement can help to figure out this issue. The command I used gives an output of all ranges of the second file that are overlapped with the first object, in other words, if all SNPs (1 single position) of object 2 are overlapping with those of object 1, consequently they are contained within the range and the number of ranges from the output will be the same as the number of ranges from the object 2. But as I explained later, this was not the problem anyway.

Comment: @StupidWolf The problem is that, there are some markers that cannot be processed by the getSeq function, and I don't know why that happens, I don't know either what else could I check about them . Since when I perform exactly the same task using another algorithm in bash (see below in my question), it gives me the desired sequence for that marker.

Comment: The issue is not with ambiguous base pairs.. this is simple to prove. just write a fasta file 1 contig, 10bp, with 1 ambigious base and you can see it is read in properly..  Which means the issue is the genomic ranges. Another thing you can try is to read in the fasta file using Biostrings, and subset and you will see that it throws an error too